# Javascript: Printing array of a constructor class

Tags: javascript, node.js

Posting only the parts needed.

```
    // This program simulates purchases of musical albums through a loop. 
// The user initially has 1000 dollars. As the program loops through the albums
// the user purchases random quantities. The program adds the subtotals and 
// subtracts from the initial total to find out what the user has left. 

// Variables for random quantity. 
var min = 1,
    max = 25;

// Constructor for Album class
function Album(title, artist, price, release){
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.price = price;
    this.release = release;
    this.quantity = (Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min);
    this.subtotal = this.quantity * this.price;

};
Album.prototype.purchase = function(){
    this.quantity--;
    if (this.quantity > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
};

// Constructor for Cart class
function Cart(val){
    this.items = [];
};

Cart.prototype.add = function(val){
    this.items.push(val);
};

Cart.prototype.remove = function(val){
    this.items.splice(albums.indexOf(val), 1);
};

// Object that inherit from the Album class.
var nothingSame = new Album('Nothing Was the Same', "Drake", 15.99, "09/24/2013");
nothingSame.tracklisting = ["Started from the Bottom", "All Me", "Pound Cake", "The Language"];

var lifeOfPablo = new Album("The Life of Pablo", "Kanye West", 15.98, "02/14/2016");
lifeOfPablo.tracklisting = ["Ultralight Beam", "Famous", "Feedback", "Low Lights"];

var babel = new Album("Babel", "Mumford & Sons", 13.83, "09/21/2012");
babel.tracklisting = ["I Will Wait", "Lover of the Light", "Whispers in the Dark", "Babel"];

var ghostStories = new Album("Ghost Stories", "Coldplay", 12.61, "05/16/2014");
ghostStories.tracklisting = ["Magic", "Midnight", "A Sky Full of Stars", "True Love"];

var trueAlbum = new Album("True", "Avicii", 15.99, "09/13/2013");
trueAlbum.tracklisting = ["Wake Me Up", "You Make Me", "Hey Brother", "Lay Me Down"];

// Array of the albums for the objects within them.
var albums = [nothingSame, lifeOfPablo, babel, ghostStories, trueAlbum];

//Variables the initial amount of money
var INITIAL_MONEY = 1000.00;
var n = 1000.00;

// Instance of cart.
var cart = new Cart();

// Loop that simulates the purchase. 
var i = 0;
while(INITIAL_MONEY > 0 && i < albums.length){
    if (INITIAL_MONEY >= albums[i].subtotal){
        albums[i].purchase();
        INITIAL_MONEY = INITIAL_MONEY - albums[i].subtotal;
        cart.add(albums[i]);
    }
    i++;
}

// Variable for the total amount spent.
var total = n - INITIAL_MONEY;

// Console logs to output all the data to the user. 
console.log("You walk into a store with $1000 and purchase several albums.")
console.log(cart);
console.log("Total: " + total.toFixed(2));
console.log("Money Remaining: " + INITIAL_MONEY.toFixed(2));
```

Output Example:

```
You walk into a store with $1000 and purchase several albums.
Cart {
  items: 
   [ Album {
       title: 'Nothing Was the Same',
       artist: 'Drake',
       price: 15.99,
       release: '09/24/2013',
       quantity: 22,
       subtotal: 367.77,
       tracklisting: [Object] },
     Album {
       title: 'The Life of Pablo',
       artist: 'Kanye West',
       price: 15.98,
       release: '02/14/2016',
       quantity: 1,
       subtotal: 31.96,
       tracklisting: [Object] },
     Album {
       title: 'Babel',
       artist: 'Mumford & Sons',
       price: 13.83,
       release: '09/21/2012',
       quantity: 1,
       subtotal: 27.66,
       tracklisting: [Object] },
     Album {
       title: 'Ghost Stories',
       artist: 'Coldplay',
       price: 12.61,
       release: '05/16/2014',
       quantity: 4,
       subtotal: 63.05,
       tracklisting: [Object] },
     Album {
       title: 'True',
       artist: 'Avicii',
       price: 15.99,
       release: '09/13/2013',
       quantity: 18,
       subtotal: 303.81,
       tracklisting: [Object] } ] }
Total: 794.25
Money Remaining: 205.75
```

I can't figure out how to get the track listing to show. Closest I got to it, it only showed the last track in the array for all of them. I can't seem to get each of the albums to display the listed tracks in the output.

Comment: How did you produce your output? Using `toString`?

Comment: No I have each of the albums being put into the cart. Then I just used console.log(cart); to print out the whole album class.

Comment: `console.log` implementation depends on your browser.  For example, in Chrome it looks like `Album
artist: "Drake"
price: 15.99
quantity: 1
release: "09/24/2013"
subtotal: 15.99
title: "Nothing Was the Same"
tracklisting: Array[4]` where `Array[4]` is clickable/expandable to show the elements.

Comment: The fact that it shows `[Object]` in your output suggests that you are doing what you want, in that tracklisting is an array object.

Comment: I am using the terminal on my mac. I'll run in a browser and see what I get. If it works then I can just turn it in as is.

Comment: See my answer, assuming `JSON` is installed on your terminal JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: What program are you using to run your js? node?

Comment: yes, that is what I am using.

Comment: Should have `JSON` lib. Try updated answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output this for debugging or `toString` purposes, you can try `JSON.stringify(albums, null, 2)`.

If you want it displayed in the console, using `console.log`, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(albums, null, 2))`

Edit:

Applied to your `Cart` implementation, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(cart, null, 2))` in place of `console.log(cart)`.

Sample output

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "Nothing Was the Same",
      "artist": "Drake",
      "price": 15.99,
      "release": "09/24/2013",
      "quantity": 18,
      "subtotal": 303.81,
      "tracklisting": [
        "Started from the Bottom",
        "All Me",
        "Pound Cake",
        "The Language"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "The Life of Pablo",
      "artist": "Kanye West",
      "price": 15.98,
      "release": "02/14/2016",
      "quantity": 15,
      "subtotal": 255.68,
      "tracklisting": [
        "Ultralight Beam",
        "Famous",
        "Feedback",
        "Low Lights"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Babel",
      "artist": "Mumford & Sons",
      "price": 13.83,
      "release": "09/21/2012",
      "quantity": 16,
      "subtotal": 235.11,
      "tracklisting": [
        "I Will Wait",
        "Lover of the Light",
        "Whispers in the Dark",
        "Babel"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "True",
      "artist": "Avicii",
      "price": 15.99,
      "release": "09/13/2013",
      "quantity": 10,
      "subtotal": 175.89000000000001,
      "tracklisting": [
        "Wake Me Up",
        "You Make Me",
        "Hey Brother",
        "Lay Me Down"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works but the structure is a little wacky. I'm not sure if it's just the terminal or not though.

Comment: The structure should look like the output in the answer.  As mentioned in previous comments on the question, `console.log` is interpreter specific so running it in Chrome vs Firefox vs node vs IE vs something else can and probably will give you different results.  JSON is a standard library that should produce the same output across interpreters.  If you want the exact same output, you'd likely have to create a toString() for your objects that replicates node's `console.log`.

Comment: Alright. I understand it. Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the album instances tracklisting property manually, you can get the individual items:

```
 // Loop over the albums array
 for(var i = 0; i < albums.length; ++i){
     // Loop through the tracklisting array elements for the current album
     for(var x = 0; x < albums[i].tracklisting.length; ++x){
        console.log(albums[i].tracklisting[x]);
     }
 }
```

But, how about:

```
   var albumString = JSON.stringify(albums);
   console.log(albumString);
```

To simply turn the entire object structure into a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to dump the contents of the created object to console, then it's not much of a js problem, but more of dealing with quirks of the console you're using... E.g. some consoles collapse nested objects.

In most cases you can dump the objects to string and output that, it's a good debugging aproach (which additionally gives you a view of an object from the time of the console call execution, not a reference to an object that might change later):

```
JSON.stringify(albums);
```

so in typical console call:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(albums));
```